SQL Server Replication procedure or function sp_get_redirected_publisher has too many arguments specified
Replication stopped working on a SQL Server 2022 to SQL Server 2022 setup. Snapshot replication, one subscriber. As far as I am aware nothing changed.
I am getting the following error message, every minute or so:

Procedure or function sp_get_redirected_publisher has too many arguments specified. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22037)

There is nothing on this error to be found anywhere, searching on the error number yields nothing.
I have tried regenerating a snapshot.
